# Automatically fixing multiple errors using Fix topology error tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, topology

I am an ArcGIS 10 user.

I want to solve multiple errors using the fix topology error. I select all my features, I click right but I don't have  the correcting options (Snap, trim, extent), I only have Delete.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: What topology rules do you have on your geodatabase? If you are selecting all the features with different topology errors it will disable all but the delete options.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the very quick reply. I have just one rule "Points must be covered by endpoints of lines", and I am selecting just the points feature. I have a couple of points outside the line. Still nothing. Don't know why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the point rule, "Must Be Covered By Endpoint Of," the only automated topology fix available is Delete. Other fixes, such as snap and trim, do not apply to this rule.

See the very end of this help topic: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Geodatabase_topology_rules_and_topology_error_fixes/001t000000sp000000/

This topic lists all the topology rules, their fixes, and whether or not they can be applied to more than one error at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much again. I found out meanwhile that you cannot make multiple fixes for all the rules. Didn't know that.