# Repairing all topology errors at once in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, topology

In 2012 an ArcMap user wrote [Automatically fixing multiple errors using Fix topology error tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/21988/115):

> I am a ArcGIS.10. user. I'm want to solve multiple errors using the
>   fix topology error. So I select all my features I click right but I
>   don't have the correcting options (Snap, trim, extent), I only have
>   Delete. Does anyone know why?

Now I have about the same problem with overlapping line features which I would like to correct with subtract without the need to select and subtract each single error.

Is there in 2018 the option to correct all errors in one go?

For overlapping line features there is only the option to subtract, but still when I select multiple errors the option to use subtract is greyed out.

Currently I have more than 10000 errors in a big data set of an indoor environment.

Comment: The 2012 question referenced: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21988/fix-topology-error-tool-cant-automatically-fix-multiple-errors

Comment: I doubt this is possible. Options which could cause significant data loss are removed when multiple error are selected. If you have 10k errors, you probably want to use Integrate with larger tolerances first.

Comment: Using arcobjects, it would be possible to write a command to loop through each `ITopologyEdge` and write them as features to a new line featureclass (or featureclasses), skipping over the ones that have more than one Parent.

Comment: Please write that up as a self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did find a very useful hint on how to handle this problem. See the following [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/90426/118018) to [Merging overlapping line segments in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90409)

The author uses the dissolve tool to reduce overlapping line features. Now I do not have any errors anymore.So, my solution was to first use the **dissolve tool** . This reduces overlapping line features or deletes them completely. I then validate it with the creation of a topology with the rule 'should not overlap'. The very few errors (I did not have any...) could then be deleted manually with the error inspector.