# Using Topology in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology

I am using  ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.1.

I am trying to fix a dataset that has several holes throughout it. I built a topology to identify any area that does not have gaps or overlaps. However, when I run the error check, the identified gaps come in as polylines and it will not give me the option to fill them.

Has anyone encountered this and have a workaround?

There doesn't seem to be anywhere to specify what feature type the error should represent itself as.

I can click "create a feature," but I'd rather merge that in with the surrounding polygon than create a separate feature for it.

Comment: Do you have a picture of what the issue is? It is sometimes easier to understand the problem by looking at it.

Comment: This is an expected behaviour, creating a feature, since it cannot be "guessed" which polygon that this new feature will be merged. You can [fix errors in bulk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288297/repairing-all-topology-errors-at-once-in-arcmap) and then use [Eliminate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm) or [Eliminate Polygon Parts](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate-polygon-part.htm) tools depending on your problem.

Comment: @fatih_dur Those tools did the trick. That was what I was looking to do, but did not know those tools were available. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad this solved your problem. I will move my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour, creating a feature, since it cannot be "guessed" which polygon that this new feature will be merged. You can [fix errors in bulk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288297/repairing-all-topology-errors-at-once-in-arcmap) and then use [Eliminate](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate.htm) or [Eliminate Polygon Parts](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/eliminate-polygon-part.htm) tools depending on your problem.